# Independent component in ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, components

I don't know how to ask about this problem in google ...
I mean, I have a product array where I use *ngFor.
And now in a single component "product" - I have a variable "loading: boolean" .... When I change the "loading" state in one component, the state also changes in other components. How to make a component independent in ngFor ...?
How do you solve such problems? After all, this should be a common problem, and there is hardly a word about it on the internet ...

Example (Pseudo angular code):

Parent.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let product in products">
  <app-product>
  </app-product>
</div>
```

Product.component.ts

```
export class Product implements ngOnInit {

}

bla, bla, bla...

loading: boolean = false;
```

...And when I change the state of the variable "loading" - it changes that state in all components, and I want it to change in only one component.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing that, you should try to take a step back and keep components simple, following the single responsibility principle (Read the angular style guide for more best practices: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility).

Something generally done would be to have a single loading component, with a template that looked like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="loading; else showProducts">
  <loading></loading>
</div>
<ng-template #showProducts>
  <div *ngFor="let product in products">
    <app-product>
    </app-product>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

However, if your use case won't work with this pattern, you could use an input property for your component. Example:

Product.component.ts

```js
export class Product {
  @Input() loading: boolean;
}
```

Parent.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let product in products">
  <app-product [loading]="true"><!-- instead of true, use a variable from parent component -->
  </app-product>
</div>
```